# Оптимизация сайта под телефон

Tags: вёрстка, html5, css3, веб-программирование, адаптивная-верстка

Добрый день, Я использую адаптивную вереску сайта, когда я включаю на телефоне с узким экраном то сайт можно сдвинуть в право и получается, что сайт можно болтать в право, лево. Как это исправить? Мне надо что бы май точно встал в рамки телефона и не шатался в право, лево. Сайт http://vectorsporta.ru/

Comment: вы можете скинуть код подключения карты гугл

Comment: Это стандартная карта маленького размера от Google

Comment: ширина у карты установлена ?

Comment: заключите `iframe` карт Google в `<div style="max-width:400px">`, а в самом `iframe` вместо `width="400"` укажите `width="100%"`, и останется только отцентрировать это всё